# Agent oversign using Sabre Web Services

Tags: sabre

After performing a ContextChangeLLSRQ, we get USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED when we attempt to use the new (agent's) BST on certain services e.g. MISCServicesRQ. It seems agent EPR need to be setup in ICE which cannot happen since SWS access is supposed to be just for apps. Anybody else encounter this and how did you address?

Answer (score 1):

USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED means that the user does not have the necessary attributes to consume the service.
It simply needs to be provisioned, engage the airline's Account Director.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work without needing to setup **every** individual user? Because it would become an access management nightmare very quickly because a list of users is not as static as a list of applications.

Comment: You have limited amount of users enabled for consuming services in general. Just give the list of users you want to be able to consume the service to the Account Director and he/she will do whats necessary.
Still, I'm sure it is not necessary in every user.